# multiple ifelse condtion in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to use if-else to recode a column based on two conditions. Here is an example of data.

```
score.1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
cat <- c("a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e")

data <- data.frame("score.1"=score.1,"cat"=cat)

cut.score.1 <- 2.5
cut.score.2 <- 7.5

data[,1] <- ifelse(data[,1] < cut.score.1, data[,1] == cut.score.1, data[,1])
data[,1] <- ifelse(data[,1] > cut.score.2, data[,1] == cut.score.2, data[,1])

> data[,1]
 [1] 0 0 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0
```

However, when the condition/s meet, Os are printed. Any thoughts on that?

Thanks

Comment: `data[,1] == cut.score.1` returns TRUE / FALSE in other words 1 and 0. So you assign 0 for those which met the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The "yes" argument is returning a logical vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` (`TRUE` if `data[, 1]` is the same as the cut score and `FALSE` if not. When converted to numeric, `FALSE` is - and `TRUE` is 1. Try removing this and just returning the cut score as follows:

```r
data[,1] <- ifelse(data[,1] < cut.score.1, cut.score.1, data[,1])
data[,1] <- ifelse(data[,1] > cut.score.2, cut.score.2, data[,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Working tidyverse alternative using mutate and case_when for posterity.

```
dplyr::mutate(data, score.1 = dplyr::case_when(
  score.1 > cut.score.2 ~ cut.score.2,
  score.1 < cut.score.1 ~ cut.score.1,
  TRUE ~ score.1
))

   score.1 cat
1      2.5   a
2      2.5   b
3      3.0   c
4      4.0   d
5      5.0   e
6      6.0   a
7      7.0   b
8      7.5   c
9      7.5   d
10     7.5   e
```